# How do I delete an Item from an array save on local storage?

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage

I'm trying to delete an item from a fav list saved on state and localStorage

action.js

```
export function addFavoriteAction(personaje) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch( addFavorite(personaje));
    }
}

const addFavorite = (personaje) => ({
    type: ADD_FAV,
    payload: personaje
});

export function removeFavoriteAction(personaje) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch( removeFavorite(personaje));

        const favArray  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'))
        console.log(favArray)
        favArray.splice(favArray.includes(personaje), 1)
        localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(favArray));
    }
}

const removeFavorite = (personaje) => ({
    type: REMOVE_FAV,
    payload: id
});
```

I also have this function a component to handle which dispatch use but I'm not 100% sure about this:

```
  const handleFav = () => {

    if(favorites.map(favorite => favorite.id === perSelect.id)) {
      
      dispatch( removeFavoriteAction(perSelect));
    } else {
      dispatch( addFavoriteAction(perSelect));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your redux setup is not ideal. Take a look at [Redux style guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.filter()` method

```
 localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(favArray.filter(fav => fav.id !== id)));
```